# Can the formula for finding the slope of a line be reversed and still be right?

Tags: geometry

The formula for finding the slope of a line is $y_2-y_1\over x_2-x_1$, but can it be reversed into $y_1-y_2\over x_1-x_2$ and still be right?

Comment: Yep, just multiply by $1 = \frac{-1}{-1}$

Comment: To expand on KB94's comment, this works because $-(a - b) = -a - (-b) = -a + b = b - a$; this is happening in both the top and bottom, when multiplying by $-1/-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally,
the line through
$(x_1, y_1)$
and
$(x_2, y_2)$
has slope
$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
$.

Swapping the points,
the line through
$(x_2, y_2)$
and
$(x_1, y_1)$
has slope
$\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}
$.

But
$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}
=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}
$,
so the two lines
have the same slope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it's right.  Here's an example for (8, 5) and (4, 2):$$2-5\over 4-8$$$$-3\over-4$$$$3\over4$$and now it's time to reverse it:$$5-2\over8-4$$$$3\over4$$I can now conclude that I **can** reverse it for it to be right (except when the numerator or denominator is zero because division by zero is undefined).

Answer (score 0):

sure , for example the points (4,8) and (8,2)
if (4,8) = (x1,y1) and (8,2)=(x2,y2)
 m=y2-y1/x2-x1 = -6/4 = -3/2

also m=y1-y2/x1-x2 = 6/-4 = -3/2 .

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math, so they can appear cleaner.